# Is it defined in C to access "extra" union space via pointer to char?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

The C standard permits accessing an object via a pointer to character type (§6.3):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue that has one of the following
> types:
> [...]
>
> - a character type

This allows functions like `memcpy()` and `fwrite()` to work.

Say I have a union type used for a variant type (aka. a tagged union):

```c
union var_uint
{
    uint8_t  n1;
    uint32_t n4;
};

enum kind_t
{
    KIND_1,
    KIND_4
};

struct tagged_uint
{
    enum  kind_t   kind;
    union var_uint value;
};
```

The C standard also says:

- the size of a union is the size of its largest member, and there may be unnamed padding at the end of the union
- type punning (accessing a union member via another member that's a char array) is implementation defined (I think it should also be legal to access it via a char array that isn't a member as per above?)

Is it defined behaviour to access the full size of the union type via a char pointer, even if you don't actually have any logic that depends on the values of the padding bytes? For example:

```c
union var_uint number;
number.n1 = 127;
struct tagged_uint tagged_number = { KIND_1, number };
fwrite(&tagged_number, sizeof (union var_uint), 1, my_stream);

// Later.

struct other_tagged_number;
fread(&other_tagged_number, sizeof (union var_uint), 1, my_reopened_stream);
```

Here the padding bytes must be accessed to be written to the stream, even though it makes no difference to the logic of the code later (assuming it checks the `kind` field before accessing the `var_uint` member).

I only have the C90 standard with me right now, but I'd be interested in what the other standards say too.

(I am not actually serialising data to disk in this way.)

Comment: One question: why?

Comment: @wildplasser It's obvious: to write the union to a byte stream in a generic way.

Comment: If it's not valid, IMHO it's a bug in the standard. You should be able to access all the bytes of any type when treating it as a `char` array.

Comment: I think the "stored value" of a `struct` or `union` comprises all its bytes, including the padding.

Comment: Well, you have to divide and conquer: check the type, and decide to either write union member one, or write union membert two. (the same for reads)

Comment: @wildplasser: But that's the question - do you *have* to?  (It's probably a more common issue with `memcpy` than `fwrite/fread`, but it's the same question.)

Comment: @wildplasser Basically @Barmar has it — *one* instance of this is, I'm using an IPC library for embedded work and trying to figure out if I can save code size and cycles by switching only on the deserialisation of the `kind` field and not the serialisation. Currently I am using your "divide and conquer" approach. (I didn't want the IPC thing to be a red herring though, I've seen it in other code too and I'm curious.)

Comment: @wildplasser (I admit I had the same reaction as you when I saw it, which is partly why I want a definitive answer. You know, so I can sleep at night.)

Comment: Instead of dumping the raw structure as a pile of bytes, you may want to serialize it more carefully. The padding can be stripped if you include a "type" byte. This can help with portability issues where the `union` layout may not be consistent, and/or endian issues which may crop up with the numbers themselves. It's often the case the in-memory representation is different from a serialized representation for saving on disk or transmitting over a network connection, etc.

Comment: @detly: 6.5.6.1 explicitly lets you memcpy any object to somewhere else and then memcpy it back. But it's not restricted to memcpy (the standard says something like "for example, with memcpy") and I'd say that writing and reading from a file (only in binary mode, of course) is equally acceptable. I don't think that clause has changed.

Comment: Oops, 6.2.6.1. sorry.

Comment: @tadman - that's good advice, and it's what I'm currently doing. In less constrained environments I would even suggest using a proper serialisation library. I'd like to know more about this edge case though.

Answer (score 3):

6.2.6.1 of the C99 spec has two relevant paragraphs:

> When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member
> object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take
> unspecified values. The values of padding bytes shall not affect whether the value of
> such an object is a trap representation. Those bits of a structure or union object that are
> in the same byte as a bit-field member, but are not part of that member, shall similarly not
> affect whether the value of such an object is a trap representation.
>
> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object
> representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members
> take unspecified values, but the value of the union object shall not thereby become a trap
> representation.

Thus accessing the padding is not undefined behavior, as long as you use a type (such as char) that cannot have any trap values.

Comment: The bulk of the C89 Standard was written under a presumption that every object that would fit within any region of accessible storage would either hold a valid value or a trap representation, and that the behavior of accessing any such object that didn't hold a trap representation would be defined.  Neither it, nor any subsequent version, has sought to *fully* categorize situations where attempts to access objects that don't hold trap representations may yield UB anyway.

Comment: I suspect the statement that the object won't become a trap representation was intended to imply that accessing it would not yield UB unless one attempted to access an individual member that happened to hold a trap representation, but the fact that the union object doesn't become a trap representation doesn't actually guarantee that.

Comment: The C standard does not prohibit `char` from having trap representations. Use `unsigned char`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: 6.2.6.1.5 in C99 only allows trap representations for values "that does not have character type" -- which implies none of `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` can have trap representations.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: That paragraph tells you that reading an object containing a trap representation with a non-character type has undefined behavior, and that may be intended to imply that reading it with a character type does not have undefined behavior, but that still does not imply the representation is not a trap representation. It just means that you can read it. Then you have a `char` that does not have a defined value. Maybe this is a defect in the standard, but this not saying that `char` objects do not have trap representations, just that reading them is not explicitly undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: What is a trap representation, if not an object which, if read, would put the program's behavior outside the Standard's jurisdiction?

Answer (score 0):

The C89 Standard as a whole was, like the language it was written to describe, based around an abstraction model where every addressable object of type T that would fit in a region of storage will hold, based on the contents of the sizeof (T) bytes at its address, hold either a value of its type or a trap representation.  Attempting to read the object when it holds a value will yield that value; the consequences of attempting to read an object when it holds a trap representation are outside the Standard's jurisdiction.  Note that under this model, anything which is said about the behavior of writing one object in a union and reading another would apply equally to code which e.g. writes an object with a pointer of another type, converts the pointer to a different type, and then reads the object using that.

A lot of the vagueness about structures and unions was intended to accommodate implementations where writing to larger areas of memory might be faster than writing to smaller ones.  For example, if a little-endian platform supports 8-bit and 32-bit reads and writes, but not 16-bit ones, and one has a structure type:

```
struct foo {
  uint16_t a,b,c; // Followed by 16 bits of padding
  uint32_t d;
} *p;
```

it might be faster to process `p->c = 23;` by storing 23 to the 32-bit word holding `p->c`, than by using a pair of 8-bit writes.  If, however, there were also a structure type:

```
struct bar {
  uint16_t a,b,c,d;
} my_bar;
```

and one were to perform `p->c = 23;` while `p` pointed to `my_bar`, such an action would corrupt the value of `my_bar.d`.  Although there would be some situations where it would be useful to be able to read and write common-initial-sequence members, allowing CIS members to be written as well as read would have made it necessary for a compiler processing `p->c = 23;` to use a pair of byte stores rather than a word store, possibly incurring a major speed penalty.  The authors of the Standard likely figured that implementations that would have no reason to process writes in that fashion could and would extend the language by processing CIS writes in a way that avoids corrupting nearby objects, regardless of whether the Standard would require that they do so, and thus there was no need to have the Standard address the behavior of CIS writes.

Although the Standard seems to hint that for every object of type `T`, there exists a `char[sizeof (T)]` object which occupies the same storage, and that actions may be performed using the latter object to access the storage associated with the former with the semantics implied by the original abstraction model, it doesn't actually say that such an object exists.  Given e.g.

```
union foo {
  unsigned char x[2];
  int y;
} it;
```

the Standard never makes clear whether the pointer expression `(unsigned char*)it` yields a pointer to the first element of the `char[sizeof (union foo)]` object which implicitly overlays `it`, rather than e.g. a pointer to the first element of a `char[2]` object `u.x` (which would of course share the same address).

Note that such ambiguities don't create situations where there a piece of code might have two different defined behaviors in some circumstances.  In nearly all such cases, it's clear that behavior is either defined unambiguously or not defined at all.  If compilers treat constructs as having the unambiguously-defined behaviors in cases where doing so would be sensible, regardless of whether the Standard requires them to do so, it won't matter if the Standard leaves ambiguous the question of *whether* the behaviors are defined.  Unfortunately, compiler writers and programmers are often at odds about when it is "sensible" to treat as UB an action that could have only one possible defined meaning.

I don't think any of today's compilers are apt to behave nonsensically in the circumstances you describe, but I don't think the Standard would forbid it.  Instead, it relies upon compiler writers to exercise common sense, and in this particular situation, so far as I can tell, they haven't thrown common sense out the window.